# Cocoapods not showing my project as Tested

Tags: ios, cocoapods, podspec

I have a project that I've added as a Cocoapod. It is covered by tests, yet the Cocoapods project page does not show the tests. Here is the link to my project page:

https://cocoapods.org/pods/SKTableViewDataSource

Note, `Tested: X` in the right hand column.

This is what my podspec looks like:

```
Pod::Spec.new do |spec|

spec.name = 'SKTableViewDataSource'
spec.version = '1.0.0'
spec.license = 'MIT'
spec.summary = 'An easy to configure data source for UITableView.'
spec.homepage = 'https://github.com/skladek/SKTableViewDataSource'
spec.authors = { 'Sean Kladek' => 'skladek@gmail.com' }
spec.source = { :git => 'https://github.com/skladek/SKTableViewDataSource.git', :tag => spec.version }
spec.ios.deployment_target = '9.0'
spec.source_files = 'Source/*.swift'
end
```

Do I need to add something to the podspec or elsewhere to have it recognize my tests?

Comment: Did you follow recommended folder structure? Is code coverage enabled? How many tests do you have?

Comment: I'm using the same folder structure that I've seen in other Pod projects. I haven't seen anywhere where they document the expected folder structure. Maybe I missed it. Code coverage is enabled, both travis-ci.org and codecov.io are able to run the tests and generate a coverage report respectively. There are 59 tests in the project.

Comment: Seems right https://guides.cocoapods.org/making/using-pod-lib-create.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a ticket in the cocoadocs.org project:

> Apparently it comes from the © character in the headers added by Xcode when creating a new Swift file, like in the following line:
>
> ```
> //  Copyright © 2017 pirishd. All rights reserved.
> ```
>
> Removing this character in all the Swift files of the Test target makes detection work again.

https://github.com/CocoaPods/cocoadocs.org/issues/523

Removing the copyright headers from my test files worked for me.